# find . -print0 | xargs -0 cmd vs find . -exec cmd {} +

Tags: find, xargs

- `find . -exec cmd {} +`
- `find . -print0 | xargs -0 cmd`

Both are meant to be reliable ways to run a command on the files found by find.

Which is preferred? Which is more portable, reliable, efficient, versatile and why?

Answer (score 28):

### TL;DR

There's no clear winner. My recommendation would be to use:

```
find . -exec cmd {} +
```

Wherever it's enough as it's more portable, uses less resource and has fewer issues, and one of:

```
xargs -r0 -other-options -a <(find ... -print0 | ...) cmd
```

```
find . -print0 | ... | xargs -0 -other-options cmd
```

When you need additional features of `xargs` or post-process the output of
`find` with other tools and you know you're on a system that supports those
non-standard options and the limitations don't apply and/or can be ignored.

### History

`find` has had `-exec cmd {} ';'`, the variant which runs one invocation of
`cmd` per file and also acts as a condition predicate, since its reimplementation with the current interface in
Unix V5 in the mid-70s, but the `-exec cmd {} +` form which passes
several files to `cmd`,  as many as possible, came much later. It was written by
David Korn and first released in System V Release 4 in 1988 (See `lynx news://news.gmane.io/gmane.comp.standards.posix.austin.general/2192`) though
not documented until SVR4.2 (1992).

It was only [added to the 2001 edition of the POSIX standard](/a/320172) and some
implementations of `find` only added it much later (4.2.12, in 2005 for GNU
`find`, 2002 for FreeBSD, 2006 for NetBSD, 2015 for busybox)

`xargs` itself is from PWB Unix from the late 70s. It had (and still has) a very
poor interface with weird and unnecessary features and limitations,
understanding a unique form of quoting (though to be fair close to that
understood by PWB Unix shell which hasn't survived). Though it was meant to
work on the output of `find`, it could not do so reliably.

A `-0` option was added to GNU `xargs` alongside a new `-print0` option to GNU
`find` in 1990. It's pretty safe to assume the GNU `find` authors were not
aware of SysV's `-exec {} +` when they added that. Some
`-0`/`--null`/`-z`/`--zero` options have been gradually added to other GNU
utilities after that to handle that NUL-delimited *interchange* format that can carry arbitrary file
paths and more generally arbitrary C strings or command line arguments.

A `-d` option to `xargs` to allow any single-byte record delimiter,  making `-0` redundant as it's then just the same as `-d '\0'` was added much later to GNU xargs (in 4.2.26 released in late 2005) but to this day and to my knowledge is still only supported by GNU `xargs`.

Without those `-0` or `-d` (and `-r`, see below), `xargs` is hardly usable
(reliably).

`-print0`/`-0` have been added since to a few other implementations, even on
some commercial SysV-derived Unixes such as Solaris 11. It is also supported by
the `find` builtin of the `bosh` shell.

They are not standard but [might become so (along with the `-d ''` option to
the `read` utility) in the next version of the POSIX
standard](https://www.austingroupbugs.net/view.php?id=243#c6091).

### -exec cmd {} + over xargs -0 cmd

`-exec cmd {} +` is standard and now fairly portable. Its support is still
optional in busybox so you may come across Linux-based embedded systems where
it's not available. The `-ok cmd {} +` variant to prompt the user before executing `cmd` is not standard nor portable (nor would it be convenient as the command lines could end up being huge).

`-print0`/`xargs -0` is not standard, but it's now commonly found on BSDs and
in the `find`/`xargs` implementations commonly found on Linux-based systems
including GNU's, busybox' and toybox'. It's still not supported [on AIX](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/aix/7.3?topic=x-xargs-command) nor HP/UX.

Outside of GNU systems, it's also still rare
to find other implementations of the other standard utilities (`sort`, `sed`, `cut`, `awk` etc.) that support
NUL-delimited records.

`find`'s `-print0` can be implemented standardly with `-exec printf '%s\0' {} +`, but there's no standard equivalent for `xargs -0` or `sort`/`sed`/`grep`...
-z, and more generally, NULs can't be processed by POSIX text utilities (nor
file paths in general as they are not guaranteed to be text).

Except on some BSDs, `find . -print0 | xargs -0 cmd` will still run `cmd` once
without arguments if no file is found which is generally not wanted. The GNU
implementation of `xargs` added a `-r` option to avoid that but it's not as
portable as `-0`.

In `find . -exec cmd {} +`, `cmd` inherits `find`'s stdin, so `cmd` is still able
to interact with the user if that command is started from a terminal for instance.

While in `find . -print0 | xargs -r0 cmd`, depending on the `xargs`
implementation, `cmd`'s stdin will be either /dev/null (like with GNU `xargs`)
or worse will inherit `xargs`' stdin, which here is the pipe from `find`, so if
it ever reads from its stdin, it will wreak havoc. With the GNU implementation
of `xargs`, that can be worked around using `-a` and process substitution:

```
xargs -r0a <(find . -print0) cmd            # Korn syntax
xargs -r0a <{find . -print0} cmd            # rc syntax
xargs -r0a /dev/fd/3 3<(find . -print0) cmd # yash syntax
xargs -r0a (find . -print0|psub) cmd        # fish syntax (not parallel though)
```

But that's a lot less portable.

On the reliability front, in  `find . -print0 | xargs -0 cmd`, if `find` crashes or is killed early (for instance because it  has reached a resource limit), that can have dramatic consequences. That's because `find` writes its output in blocks which are not guaranteed to end on a NUL delimiter (for instance, with `find /var/tmp -name '*.tmp'`, a block might end with `/var`), and `xargs` will still make an argument to `cmd` for a non-delimited record. So for instance, here could call `cmd` (like `rm -rf`) with `/var` as argument in our example if `find` was killed after it has output a block ending in `/var`..

That problem doesn't affect `-exec cmd {} +`.

With `find . -exec cmd {} +`, the exit status reflects both `find` and `cmd` failures, while with `find | xargs`, in most shells you only get the exit status of `xargs` so could miss the fact that not all files could be found. Many shells have a `pipefail` command to alleviate that though and see also zsh's `$pipestatus` or bash's `$PIPESTATUS` which ends up giving more flexibility.

The (non-standard) `-execdir cmd -- {} +` (note the `--` needed with `find` implementations that don't add a `./` prefix to the filenames) variant which works around some of the  security issues with `-exec cmd {} +` or `xargs` cannot be done with `xargs`.

On the performance front, `find | xargs` implies more work (at least one additional process, and the shoving of that data through a pipe), and, because some of it ends up being done in parallel (`find` and `xargs` running concurrently) could end up adding contention as both `find` and `cmd` compete for I/O access, so will likely use significantly more resource overall. Thanks to that parallelism, in some situations, it may however end up carrying out the task quicker as `find` can carry on searching for more files whilst `cmd` is busy doing some CPU intensive tasks with the previous batch (at least until the pipe and `find`'s internal output buffer are both full).

With `find . -exec cmd {} +`, it's easier for `cmd` to abort the whole search. For instance, with:

```
find . -exec sh -c 'if some-condition; then kill -s PIPE "$PPID"; exit 1; fi' sh {} +
```

With `find . -print0 | xargs -0 cmd`, `cmd` can do a `exit 255` to abort `xargs`, but `find` won't exit afterwards until it tries to write the next block to the pipe.

### xargs -0 cmd over -exec cmd {} +

The main argument for those is that in the general sense, it is more generic, flexible and versatile.

`find`'s `-print0` output is a post-processable representation of a list of files that can be used by anything, not just `xargs -0`. For instance, you can do:

```
find . -print0 |
  grep -z foo |
  sort -z
```

And still get a post-processable, filtered and sorted list of file paths.

And similarly `xargs -0` can be used on those NUL-delimited lists whether they  come from the output of `find` or anything else, whether that represents file paths or anything else.

In that regard, `find . -exec cmd {} +` is only for a narrow special use case (even if it's one of the most common ones).

With `xargs`, you can use the `-n` or `-s` option to limit the number of arguments to pass to `cmd`. With GNU `xargs`, see also the `-P` option to run several instances of `cmd` in parallel, or the `xargs -0 -J {} mv {} /dest/` of some BSDs to allow extra arguments after the list of files.

You can save the output of `find . -print0` to a file and process it later (for instance, only if `find` was fully successful) with `xargs -0 cmd < file`, avoiding the output of `cmd` to interfere with the `find` result, including with things like (with GNU `xargs`):

```
xargs -r0a =(find . -print0) cmd         # zsh
xargs -r0a (find . -print0|psub -f) cmd  # fish
```

There's no equivalent of `xargs`'s `exit 255` special handling with `-exec cmd {} +` (though see above about `kill "$PPID"`).

With `find | xargs`, you can more easily run `find` and `xargs cmd` in different locales or more generally different environments (including variables, limits, umask...)

For instance, one often needs to run `find` in the C locale to work around problems with non-text filenames, but often still want `cmd` to run in the user's locale.

```
LC_ALL=C find . -exec cmd {} +
```

Runs both `find` and `cmd` in the C locale. And

```
LC_ALL=C find . -exec env -u LC_ALL cmd {} +
```

is first non-standard but also  may not restore the original locale for `cmd` if `LC_ALL` was defined beforehand.

```
LC_ALL=C find . -print0 | xargs -r0 cmd
```

Changes the locale to C for `find` only.

As a special case:

```
find . -exec sudo cmd {} +
```

Often fails to avoid the limit on the size of args+env as `sudo` happens to set a `SUDO_COMMAND` environment variable which ends up duplicating the list of arguments.

```
find . -print0 | sudo xargs -r0 cmd
```

Doesn't have the problem as `$SUDO_COMMAND` in that case only contains `xargs -0 cmd` (don't use `find . -print0 | xargs -r0 sudo cmd`).

See also:

```
sudo find . -print0 | xargs -r0 cmd
```

Where the list of files  is found by `root`, but `cmd` runs as the original user. Or

```
find . -print0 | (USERNAME=some-user; xargs -r0 cmd)
```

In shells like zsh which have builtin support to change (e)uid, (e)gids.

```
find . -print0 | xargs -r0 -- "${cmd[@]}"
```

Works whatever the `$cmd` array contains, while

```
find . -exec "${cmd[@]}" {} +
```

Fails if any of the elements of the `$cmd` array is `;` or there are `{}`, `+` consecutive elements in there.

Comment: The important stuff is a little way down after the history section. The history section mainly complains about incompatibility of older systems ( it reads like don't use more than 8.3 filenames, because some people. Back in 1991 the first thing I did on a new system was install the GNU tools, so should not be a problem. ) I nearly did not make it to the good bit. And, the good bit is good. It contains much that should be appreciated. And continues in this way all the way to the end.