# Handle parentheses in this xargs multi-command

Tags: bash, shell, xargs, escape-characters

I suspect the following has been answered already but I don't know the terminology for the issue I'm having well enough to find an existing answer.

I'm working on a command to go through a list of files and output on each line the filename followed by the count of lines that start with P. I've gotten this far:

```
find -type f | xargs -I % sh -c '{ echo %; grep -P "^P \d+" % | wc -l; }  | tr "\n" ","; echo ""; '
```

<sub>(The actual find command is a bit more involved but short story is it finds about 11k files of interest in the directory tree below where I'm running this)</sub>

This command is about 98% working for my purposes, but I discovered there is a small subset of files with parentheses in their names and I can't ignore them or permanently replace the parentheses with something else.

As a result I'm getting some cases like this:

```
sh: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `('
```

I know parentheses are a shell special character so for example if I was running grep directly on a single file with parentheses in the name I'd have to enclose the filename in single quotes or escape the parentheses. I tried swapping the quote types in my command (doubles outermost, singles inner) so I could put the '%' in the grep call in single quotes but that didn't help.

Is there a way to handle parentheses in the `find -> xargs -> sh` chain so they get handled correctly in the sh call?

Comment: See also [Why is looping over find's output bad practice?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/321697) and [Is it possible to use \`find -exec sh -c\` safely?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/156008)

Comment: If you're using `find`, you don't really need to use `xargs`, (almost) everything it does can be done with find's `-exec` predicate, especially when combined with sh or some other scripting language (`e.g. -exec sh -c '...'` or `-exec perl- e'...'`.   xargs is more useful with other programs (i.e. programs-that-aren't-find). About the only time it's useful to use xargs with find is when you need parallel execution with xargs -P (and even then, there's often better tools for that job, like GNU [parallel](https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/))

Comment: @cas,  on that, see also [find . -print0 | xargs -0 cmd vs find . -exec cmd {} +](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/730873)

Comment: oh yeah, filtering/manipulating the file list with grep/sed/awk/perl/whatever (NUL-separated, of course) *between* `find ... -print0` and `xargs -0r` is also a good reason to use xargs instead of -exec.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Better not embed data (filenames) directly in code (the shell scriptlet). Instead pass the filename as an argument to the shell you have `xargs` run:

```
find -type f | xargs -I % \
  sh -c '{ echo "$1"; grep -c -P "^P \d+" "$1"; } | tr "\n" ","; echo' sh %
```

Also you should be able to use `grep -c` instead of `grep | wc -l`, it at least makes the command a bit shorter.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! I tried your approach and it's giving me the error `sh: -c: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file`. Am I missing something?

Comment: @SSilk, there was a missing `;` before the `}` which I've added.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Yes, just saw your edit after commenting. It's working for me now. Thanks!

Comment: @ilkkachu Re: `grep -c`, thanks for the reminder. I was pretty sure grep had a built in counting function but when I searched for how to count matching lines with grep the first thread I found only showed piping grep matches into `wc -l`. So I just ran with that.

Comment: Acknowledging that there are some good recommendations in other answers about using `find -exec` rather than ``xargs`, I'm accepting this answer as it directly answers the initial question of how to handle parentheses in filenames in specific scenario.

Answer (score 3):

Since you omitted the `.` in `find . -type f`, I suppose your `find` is GNU `find`, then you can do:

```
find . -type f -printf %p, -exec grep -cP '^P \d' {} ';'
```

If the file paths don't contain `:` characters, you could also do (with GNU `grep`):

```
grep -rcP '^P \d' . | tr : ,
```

If they may contain `:` characters but don't contain newline characters, that can be worked around by replacing only the last `:` in the line with `,`:

```
grep -rcP '^P \d' . | LC_ALL=C sed 's/\(.*\):/\1,/'
```

That approach can also be used with:

```
find ... -type f -exec grep -cHP '^P \d' {} + | ...
```

If you still need to use `find`, for instance because you have more selection criteria.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I think the issue with this approach is my real find command is a bit involved. (Finds files, recursively, only those with numerical extensions, rejects those with spaces and certain special characters, but does allow a few special characters like parentheses. So not something I know how to do with grep's built in filename filtering.).  It just didn't have much bearing on the question I was asking so I shortened it to what's shown above.

Comment: @SSilk, you can still use `find` with that approach, see edit.

Answer (score 0):

[ilkkachu's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/743420/40482) looks like a fine improvement and is probably what you should do.

Adding, for information purposes, a lighter touch fix to show where your problem lies:

```
find -type f | xargs -I % sh -c '{ echo "%"; grep -P "^P \d+" "%" | wc -l; }  | tr "\n" ","; echo ""; '
```

Basically -- quote wrap the `%` that will be replaced.

Comment: Even with quotes, that's still a command injection vulnerability (like with a `$(reboot)` file). The place holder should **never** be embedded in the code argument.

Comment: Thanks for the tip.

Comment: Thanks for the info. These finer details of embedding place holders vs passing as arguments is new to me. I'll have to study up on it. The method I was using was demonstrated in the following post https://linuxize.com/post/linux-xargs-command/#:~:text=To%20run%20multiple%20commands%20with,the%20argument%20passed%20to%20xargs.

Comment: Also: no need for `xargs` (and find's output is not compatible with xargs expected input format unless you use `-print0`/`-0`) as you can use `find`'s `-exec`. No need to run one `sh` per file as `sh` can loop over arguments. `echo` can't be used for arbitrary data. `See `paste -sd , -` to join lines with `,`.